# Does the Log4J vulnerability impact Snowflake's Snowpark library? Does SLF4J act as a facade for Log4J at any point in the Snowpark api?

Tags: scala, log4j, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is Snowflake's Snowpark Scala API and its SLF4J dependency open to the Log4j vulnerability? How can I determine exposure?

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not and we communicated that officially [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/No-Snowflake-exposure-to-Apache-Log4j-vulnerability-CVE-2021-44228)

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake is not impacted and there is official note in community.

[Log4J](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/No-Snowflake-exposure-to-Apache-Log4j-vulnerability-CVE-2021-44228)